# Creating a segregated list for a malloc() clone

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

so I want to create my own malloc. I was given a library that gives me my own sbrk() function to increase my heap which basically uses malloc() to create "simulated" virtual memory.

Anyway, I stumbled across problems when implementing my free() method. Resulting in pointer confusion and questioning the whole existence of the universe. I thus create an example code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    size_t *seg_lists[4] = {NULL};

    // Allocate two memory blocks of size 2
    // First 8 bytes hold the size
    // the last 2 8 bytes partition hold the data
    void *mem1 = malloc(3*sizeof(size_t));
    void *mem2 = malloc(3*sizeof(size_t));

    // Set size fields
    *(size_t *)mem1 = 2;
    *(size_t *)mem2 = 2;

    // Move pointers to start of body
    mem1 = (size_t *)mem1 + 1;
    mem2 = (size_t *)mem2 + 1;

    // Set data to body of mem1
    size_t* mem1_first = (size_t *)mem1;
    size_t* mem1_second = (size_t *)mem1 + 1;
    *mem1_first = 100;
    *mem1_second = 200;

    // Set data to body of mem2
    size_t* mem2_first = (size_t *)mem2;
    size_t* mem2_second = (size_t *)mem2 + 1;
    *mem2_first = 300;
    *mem2_second = 400;

    // Output bodies of mem1 and mem2
    printf("mem1=[%zu|%zu|%zu]\n", *((size_t *)mem1-1), *mem1_first, *mem1_second);
    printf("mem2=[%zu|%zu|%zu]\n", *((size_t *)mem2 - 1), *mem2_first, *mem2_second);

    // We first free mem2 and add it to the seg_list with index 1
    size_t *head = seg_lists[1];
    seg_lists[1] = mem2;
    *(size_t *)mem2 = (size_t)head;

    // We now want to free mem1 and add it to the list.
    // I.e. we set the head to mem1 and the first 8 bytes of the body of
    // mem2 to the address of mem1
    head = seg_lists[1];
    seg_lists[1] = mem1;
    *(size_t *)mem1 = (size_t)head;

    // Follow first entry in seg_lists[1] and print the 2nd 8 bytes of it's body
    size_t *first = *seg_lists[1];
    printf("*first=%zu\n", *(first+1));
}
```

So first I create two memory blocks of size 2. I.e. they can hold up to 16 bytes of data. The first 8 bytes are used to store the size. So it looks like this:

```
mem1=[2|100|200]
mem2=[2|300|400]
```

Next I want to free both memory blocks. The address of the next free block should be saved in the first 8 bytes of the body of previous bloc whereas the last should always point to NULL.

After freeing `mem1`, we want `seg_list[1]` point to the address of `mem1` and the first 8 bytes of the body of `mem1` to hold `NULL`.
After freeing `mem2`, we want `seg_list[1]` to point to the address of `mem2` and the first 8 bytes of the body of `mem2` should hold the address of `mem1`.

Now, I did the "save address of `X` in the first 8 bytes of the body of `Y`" by actually saving the hex value of the address in those bytes.

Now someone kept trying to tell me that's wrong. I shouldn't do that. I can't safe the address as a value but I can't see why I couldn't. It obviously works and for me, memory just holds data. An address is a hex value which I can store as plain data and then just treat it like however I want.

So is it really that bad what I'm doing here? Shouldn't I safe an address as "plain data"?

Comment: There is something very wrong with your approach if you need to do stuff like `*(size_t *)mem1 = 2` and `mem1 = (size_t *)mem1 + 1`. I would strongly suggest you to use an appropriate `struct`, like the real `malloc()` does.

Comment: There's also the assumption that `sizeof(size_t) == sizeof(size_t*)` which might not be true. And `size_t *first = *seg_lists[1];` should lead to a warning being issued.

Comment: I don't think I'm allowed to use a `struct` but I should just work on the memory "directly"? E.g. exactly that line is something they do. And I do trust my TA's here - they might just did it for the sake of an assignment thought. (Or rather probably)

`sizeof(size_t) == sizeof(size_t*)` that's true on my system - that's good enough for now. But thanks a lot for that input! I know that isn't true, e.g. for int that would fail. Good point though.

Comment: @xotix working on the memory directly is almost always wrong. Just don't. There are several reasons because even the real malloc does not work on raw memory directly: 1) it often leads to undefined behavior; 2) it's very hard to understand and write; 3) casting the memory to a supporting `struct` type used for easy access and calculations is *costless* and there is no reason to not do it.